# Crear Tabla en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, gcloud

Hola amigos estoy tratando de crear una tabla en mis instancia de SQL, pero estoy obteniendo este error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMAR
>   Y KEY ( id )' at line 1

este es mi query

```
    CREATE TABLE Users_(  id  INT(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  ,
created_at  TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ,
name  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
lastnameP  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
lastnameM  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
pass  VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL ,
admin  BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
user  BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
owner  BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
gender  INT(1) NOT NULL ,
datenac  DATE NOT NULL , 
phone  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
,calle  VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
colonia  VARCHAR(200) NULL , 
estado  VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
cp  INT(6) NULL ,
img  VARCHAR(500) NULL ,
id_usercreated  INT(20) NOT NULL ,
status  VARCHAR(50) NULL ), PRIMARY KEY ( id );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para empezar, tienes un parentesis " ) " antes de tu primary key el cual tiene que ir al final, luego, entre el `null` y el `primary key` te hace falta la sentencia `CONSTRAINT pk_users PRIMARY KEY (id)`

Te dejo el codigo:

```
CREATE TABLE Users_(  id  INT(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  ,
created_at  TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ,
name  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
lastnameP  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
lastnameM  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
pass  VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL ,
admin  BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
user  BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
owner  BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
gender  INT(1) NOT NULL ,
datenac  DATE NOT NULL , 
phone  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
,calle  VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
colonia  VARCHAR(200) NULL , 
estado  VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
cp  INT(6) NULL ,
img  VARCHAR(500) NULL ,
id_usercreated  INT(20) NOT NULL ,
status  VARCHAR(50) NULL , CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id ) );
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Además de la respuesta de @Krey, puedes utilizar la declaración `PRIMARY KEY` al lado del campo `id`.

```
CREATE TABLE Users_(
    id  INT(50) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  -- Aqui esta el cambio.
    created_at  TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    name  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    lastnameP  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    lastnameM  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    pass  VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    admin  BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    user  BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    owner  BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    gender  INT(1) NOT NULL,
    datenac  DATE NOT NULL, 
    phone  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    calle  VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    colonia  VARCHAR(200) NULL, 
    estado  VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    cp  INT(6) NULL,
    img  VARCHAR(500) NULL,
    id_usercreated  INT(20) NOT NULL,
    status  VARCHAR(50) NULL 
);
```

Sin necesidad del `NOT NULL` como se establece en la [documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).